# Taking shots of myself on a Canon 1DX Mkii

Tags: canon, canon-1d-x

I have a Canon 1DXMkii.  I'm trying to take a shot of myself, but if I use the timer and run around to the front of the camera, it doesn't refocus on me - it stays focused where it was when I press the shutter.

Is there any way I can do this with the inbuilt camera settings, or will I need to get a remote?  Does an interval timer refocus for each shot?

Comment: I'd weigh inconvenience against repetition. If you need to do this twice a year, go with inconvenience. Twice a week, buy a remote ;)

Comment: Thanks!  I realised I do have a remote that I can trigger the timer with whilst I'm in front of the camera.  That way I get to focus and can have both my hands in the shot :)

Answer (score 2):

You can focus on the place where you will be, then switch to manual focus, start the timer and run. To make it easy you can create some mark on the ground to know where to focus and to know where to stay.

Comment: Thanks!  I realised I do have a remote that I can trigger the timer with whilst I'm in front of the camera.  That way I get to focus and can have both my hands in the shot :)